# Not getting Form value, in java

Tags: java

I have a form and bean. From bean I am retreiving values and setting in DTO. That is also setting in FORM. But getter property value is null. I don't know what is the problem here. Can anybody suggest on this?

```
import java.sql.Timestamp; 
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat; 
import java.util.ArrayList; 

public class LoginForm extends XFormBase { 
    private String title; 

    public void setTitle(String title) { 
       this.titleValue = title; 
       System.out.println(" Form set"+titleValue); 
    } 

    public String getTitle() { 
       this.title = titleValue; 
       System.out.println(" Form get"+titleValue); 
       return title; 
   } 
}
```

Comment: There is character limitation here. You can write complete words :). What are u using Struts/Spring MVC ?

Comment: can you please provide some code ?

Comment: import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class LoginForm extends XFormBase {

    
    private String title;
    
   
      public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.titleValue = title;
        System.out.println(" Form set"+titleValue);
    }


    public String getTitle() {
       this.title= titleValue;
         System.out.println(" Form get"+titleValue);
        return title;
    }

}

Comment: this is the form i have used.

Comment: Edit your question and put the code in there, rather than in a comment.

Comment: Where is titleValue delcared and initialised. If it is null, then when you call your getter, it is going to set title to null and then return that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this. I suspect a mistake in your getter and setter implementation

```
public class LoginForm extends XFormBase { 
    private String title; 

    public void setTitle(String titleValue ) { 
       this.title= titleValue; 
       System.out.println(" Form set"+this.title); 
    } 

    public String getTitle() { 
       System.out.println(" Form get"+this.title); 
       return this.title; 
   } 
}
```

Comment: @Nagarajan Can you give us the mapping Form/Object ?

Comment: Actually i getting values from bean and proc.i am able to get thevalues in DTO also. how it is setting with out get the value.. Because in the getter method value is null and setter method the exact value is there.

Comment: Sorry i am not able to share the mapping object.

Comment: @Nagarajan Perhaps your mapping is not right. I mean, Are you sure that the attribute title of the Class LoginForm is mapped with your form field?

Comment: Yes it is mapped. For test purpose i hard coded the title value in get method. It was shown in the page. So i thnk mapping is not problem

Comment: @Nagarajan If the getter works fine the setter should works fine too.

Comment: Here pbm is setter is wrking .. But getter is having null value.. i dnt how it is possible ? but its doing like this...

Comment: Then problem doesn't depend on LoginForm Class.

Comment: Fred yes you are right .. Problem not in Form. I created a new DTo and tried it was working fine. But stil am not able to find out the error.. anyhow thanks for your support ....

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is an bug:

the `setTitle` method, does not set the `title` but the `titleValue`!

I would guess the correct implementation is:

```
public void setTitle(String title) { 
   this.title = title;
   System.out.println(" Form set"+title); 
}
```

Comment: ralph sry i wrongly copied the code.. that one was i tried with some other solutions. Actually it was like this,

Comment: import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class LoginForm extends XFormBase {

    
    private String title;
    
   
      public void setTitle(String title) {        
        System.out.println(" Form set"+titleValue);
    }


    public String getTitle() {
       this.title= title;
         System.out.println(" Form get"+titleValue);
        return title;
    }

}

Comment: @Nagarajan: the code in the comment is even more worse, its setter do nothing at all! -- AND IF THE CODE IN THE QUESTION NOT THE ONE THAT YOU USE, THEN CORRECT IT!